# Want to update a table With join in oracle showing error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Update a table with Merge  update showing error Please suggest

```
 merge into IP_CO_WR2_USR.customer_tranching_data trn 
 using
 (Select distinct( trnx.cdb) , mig.EFFECTIVE_DATE EFFECTIVE_DATE 
  from SCVSTAGE.account_migration mig,
  SCVSTAGE.customer_details dtls, 
  IP_CO_WR2_USR.customer_tranching_data trnx
  where mig.EFFECTIVE_DATE <='13-MAR-17'
  and dtls.PLATFORM='SONATA' 
  and  dtls.cdb=mig.cdb_number 
  and  trnx.cdb=dtls.cdb ) x
 on (x.cdb = trn.cdb)
 when matched then 
 update 
 set trn.LAST_SENT_DATE= x.EFFECTIVE_DATE,
 trn.NEXT_DUE_DATE='07-SEP-17';
```

Please Suggest inner sub query  inside using running separately.

```
SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
30926. 00000 -  "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
*Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
           activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
*Action:   Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself other than following the instructions in the linked question?

Comment: Why you don't like the suggested PL/SQL answer ?

Comment: You accepted that answer. It seems like it meets your requirement other than the puzzling `delete from my_data_backup`( which is an odd archiving strategy). So what *additional requirement* do you have?

Comment: This is not possible using merge sql. Actualy my requirement is that i have to do archiving without using plsql, so is there any other way to it without plsql and independent query execution.

Comment: @Nitish- i have tried it using merge sql, plsql annonymous block and proc using plsql block.
Using merge sql it's not possible,plsql block is running fine but i want to know that is there any other possibilities other tha plsql block in my scenario.

Comment: @user272735- i like the PL/SQL answer but my requirement is there any other possibilities to do it without using PL/SQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my understanding the difficulty you are facing is to use that PLSQL unit in JAVA. A crude way which can simplify your life.

Also as explained MERGE is not all recomended for manipulation Source table. Here i have defined a function and called it via SQL query. Hope this helps.

```
CREATE TABLE MY_DATE AS
SELECT level col1,level||'Av' col2 FROM dual CONNECT BY level < 11;

CREATE TABLE MY_DATE_backup AS
SELECT level COL1,level||'Av' COL2 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY level < 11 AND 1 = 2;

CREATE OR REPLACE
  FUNCTION BACKUP_FUNCTION
    RETURN NUMBER
  AS
    pragma AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  BEGIN
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO MY_DATE_BACKUP
      SELECT * FROM MY_DATE;
      DELETE MY_DATE;
      COMMIT;
      RETURN 1;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN 0;
    END;
  END;

SELECT * FROM my_date;
SELECT * FROM my_date_backup;
SELECT BACKUP_FUNCTION FROM dual; -- Function Calling
```

Comment: Hi Avrajit, i am fine with your solution i used procedure instead of function, but both are using plsql block inside it, i am new to oracle is there any other way to do it without plsql, do you have nay idea about it!